# Time limit exceeded in Identifying Map Tiles on Kattis

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I'm trying to solve the problem: Identifying Map Tiles in kattis.

https://open.kattis.com/problems/maptiles2

I get the correct answer, until on the 6th test I keep getting a time limit exceeded error.

This is my code, I'm not sure what is wrong. What can I do to optimize it so it runs faster?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
s=sys.stdin.read().splitlines()

quadkey=s[0]

zoom_level=len(quadkey)

#Lists of x and y cordinates
x_cords=[]
y_cords=[]
for i in range(2**zoom_level):
    x_cords.append(i)
    y_cords.append(i)

#Try to loop through the quadkey and locate the cordinates
for i in range(len(quadkey)):
    half=int(len(x_cords)/2)
    if quadkey[i]=='0':
        x_cords=x_cords[:half]
        y_cords=y_cords[:half]
    elif quadkey[i]=='1':
        x_cords=x_cords[half:]
        y_cords=y_cords[:half]
    elif quadkey[i]=='2':
        x_cords=x_cords[:half]
        y_cords=y_cords[half:]
    elif quadkey[i]=='3':
        x_cords=x_cords[half:]
        y_cords=y_cords[half:]

x_cord=x_cords[0]
y_cord=y_cords[0]
print(zoom_level, x_cord, y_cord)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the brute force approach doesn't work is that the upper bound is 2<sup>30</sup> or 1073741824. That's a big grid to have to create and loop through, not to mention you're doing slicing on every iteration (those are copies involving loops and memory allocations).

A better approach is to find the pattern and compute it logically. My approach for this is to loop backwards through the quadkey, treating each digit as a power-of-two offset within its square.

The innermost/rightmost quadkey digit has no offset; this is the tightest box. Computing the correct offset involves simply incrementing 1 on the x and/or y axes.

Next comes the second quadkey digit from the right. This digit determines the offset within the box of 8 units that the smallest box of 4 lies within (we already figured out the quadrant for that box on step 1 and added it to the result). To figure out which quadrant in the box of 8, we need to offset the x and/or y axes of our result by 2.

Next comes the third quadkey digit from the right. This digit determines the offset within the box of 16 units that bounds the two smaller boxes we already computed the offsets for. To figure out which quadrant in the box 16, we need to offset the x and/or y axes of our result by 4.

Can you see the pattern? We're taking the powers of two as multipliers to determine each offset from the right, 1 * 2<sup>0</sup> = 1, 1 * 2<sup>1</sup> = 2, ...

If it's still not clear, I suggest spending some time with the provided diagrams on Kattis to help illustrate the approach here.

Here's the code:

```py
quadkey = input()
#                     top-left        bottom-left
quadkey_multipliers = (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)  # x, y
#                             top-right       bottom-right
x, y = 0, 0

for level, k in enumerate(reversed(quadkey)):
    xx, yy = quadkey_multipliers[int(k)]
    x += xx * 2 ** level
    y += yy * 2 ** level

print(len(quadkey), x, y)
```

Of course, direction doesn't really matter for the problem; you can iterate forwards as well, using `x += xx * 2 ** (len(quadkey) - level - 1)` in the loop, but I felt like it was easiest to reason about working backwards from the size 4 box.